# How to Clear InfoPath Cache on Server?

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath browser based form that I have been editing and publishing frequently. Is it possible to do Clear InfoPath Cache on Server before I publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once it published it auto update it, on the sharepoint side you can clear the [config cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamesway/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache/).

Info path issue mostly at client level where u have to clear the cache from local machine of users.

- browse the path and delete files to clear the cache           `C:\Documents and Settings\[User]\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\InfoPath\FormCache2`
- or use command line and run this    `Start > run > Infopath /cache clearall`

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/michael_yeager/2008/07/09/clearing-the-infopath-cache/

Comment: The reason I asked is, every time I publish the template I have to wait at least 5 minutes to use the template on my SharePoint List. Is this a normal behavior or should I clear the config cache on server?

Comment: The "config cache" clear is for the timer service.  and the infopath /cache clearall is for the local machine not the browser based forms.