# Powershell script to clear InfoPath cache

Tags: powershell

I would like to run a powershell script that will clear the InfoPath cache, Can someone help please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203102/how-to-clear-infopath-cache-on-server

Comment: above one is manual work, i would like to automate it using powershell