# Infopath validation error on some devices

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

Client getting a validation error while submitting my form in InfoPath Desktop client, but nothing is being marked with red asterisk.

> 'Some fields were not applied'
>   or
>   'Niektóre reguły nie zostały zastosowane'
>   [image: some fields were not applied]

The 'show details' button tells that required fields were markes with a red asterisk, but there are none on the form.

All the fields are filled and the strangest thing is that this is happening on some  clients - the rest of them is working just fine.
I've removed the 'required' marks on fields that haven't been present on the form.
The client has been already instructed to [clear the InfoPath Desktop App Cache folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/203107/62054).

The thing that i didn't try is to [clear the server-side](https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/archive/blogs/jamesway/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache) as stated in the answer from that question.

How can i debug this kind of a problem, and what does it mean that 'some rules were not applied'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove all standard requires (checkbox required) in the form and to replace that with a validation rule **with a good error message showing a detailed info which field has failed**

Thats a laborious solution, but it works. Thats a shame Sharepoint Designer does not have any debugging abilities...

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Central Admin under Application management --> Authentication Providers in our intranet web app settings, there is an option to enable client integration. Make sure you have selected "Yes" option.

If the issue still exists, try to republish the form and reopen, then check the results.

Comment: the problem is that the forms is working for some people...